# Why can't I pay for my $29 3 year membership?

Tags: support, jobs

I don't know if I'm being an idiot, but I can't see any way to pay the $29 dollars. I've signed into Careers, and I have the

```
Introductory offer
$29
3 year membership
until Nov 9
faq »
about »
```

but only faq and about are links. Is it because I'm from Britain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've filled out the CV to at least 50%, otherwise the filing option will not appear.

Comment: I think the "file you cv" link should be replace with some text saying you can't file until you have filled out more of you CV when the CV is not complete enough.   I hit this as well, as I wish to get the discount and therefor to pay quickly